# VueJS select a specific element in dom

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I wonder how I can select a specific element in the DOM using VueJS with our without jquery

In my component I have a method function that does this:

```
$(".u-loc input").focusin(function() {
    $(".u-loc-icon").addClass('blue-active');
});
```

The only problem is that its generated dynamic, so I could have 1 or 10 different which means I need to have a uniqe selector to each one.

So I have added `:ref="'u-loc' + index"`

Which means that I can now target the element using `$(this.$refs['u-loc' + index]);`

But I dont know how I can chain the selector to look something like this:

```
$(this.$refs['u-loc' + index]).('input').focusin(function() {
  $(this.$refs['u-loc' + index]).addClass('blue-active');
});
```

The problem is that I need to select the elements `[input]`

Answer (score 3):

You're making things very fragile with this approach. A quick fix for you would be to handle it like this.

```
<div class="input-container">
  <input @focusin="addParentClass" @focusout="removeParentClass">
</div>
```

Then have:

```
methods: {
  addParentClass (event) {
    event.target
      .closest('.input-container')
      .classList.add('blue-active')
  },
  removeParentClass (event) {
    event.target
      .closest('.input-container')
      .classList.add('blue-active')
  },
},
```

However, for the long term, you should look into breaking these into components. That way you can do something like:

```
<div :class="[containerClasses]">
  <input @focusout="isFocused = false" @focusin="isFocused = true">
</div>
```

Then have a computed property like:

```
computed: {
  containerClasses () {
    return {
      'input-container': true,
      'blue-active': this.isFocused,
    }
  },
},
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to accomplish then I think you're going wrong about it. I would add a vue.js event (focus) to all input elements:

```
<input @focus="onFocus" />
```

then I would define the onFocus method/event handler for the focus event on my Vue model:

```
methods: {
   onFocus: function (e) {
      var element = this.$el;
      var children = this.$el.childNodes;
   }
}
```

As you can see you can now get to the event envoking element via this.$el. Furthermore you can get to any child elements via this.$el.childNodes.

Comment: @Bert I'm pretty sure that when working with components "this" always refers to the component's most outer element. Since the question was not related to components then you are correct however my answer is easily fixed by using the e.target instead, as someone already pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Remember Vue is data driven so the view should reflect an underlying data model. In general you should not be injecting anything in to the DOM unless you have a specific reason to do so. In your case, what it looks like you want to di is highlight the input on focus by adding a class, so, we could have an array of input objects that have an `active` property:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods:{
    setActive(index){
        this.inputs[index].active = true;
    },
    removeActive(index){
        this.inputs[index].active = false;
    }
  },
  data: {
    inputs: [
        {value: 'foo', active: false},
        {value: 'bar', active: false}
    ]
  }
})
```

Now in your template you can use `v-for` to print all the inputs:

```
  <div v-for="(input, index) in inputs">
    <input v-model="input.value" @focusin="setActive(index)" @focusout="removeActive(index)" :class="{'blue-active' : input.active}"/> 
  </div>
```

You may notice that I'm attaching an event listener directly to each input (`@focusin` and `@focusout`), which calls a method that sets the `active` flag to `true` and `fals`e respectively for the given input (I've done that in a pretty verbose way for demonstrative purposes), I'm then using Vue's [class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) to add and remove the `blue-active` class based on that flag.

And here's the final result: https://jsfiddle.net/mooxo19v/